# Very basic VB.Net & Serial IO issue

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

After searching around I am still having issues with reading data from a serial port in VB.Net/VS2010. I know the Serial Port works, I can write to the port fine but when reading from it, nothing happens. I have only been programming for the last 3 weeks so am still trying to get my head around it all.

The program must run to capture data from a door logger, I will then be outputting the data to a database (not yet implemented - I want to get this part sorted first).
I have tried using several terminal programs as well as another device which outputs data onto the serial line, with nothing displaying in the textbox `tbxIn`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code is below:

```
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.IO.Ports.SerialPort

Public Class Form1

Dim comPort As IO.Ports.SerialPort = Nothing
Dim sComPort As String = ""
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    GetSerialPortNames()
End Sub

Sub GetSerialPortNames()
    ' Show all available COM ports.
    For Each sp As String In My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames
        lstPorts.Items.Add(sp)
    Next
End Sub


Private Sub lstPorts_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstPorts.SelectedIndexChanged
    sComPort = lstPorts.SelectedItem
    Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Open the serial port using the OpenSerialPort method
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Button2.Enabled = True

    Try
        comPort = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort(sComPort, 9600, IO.Ports.Parity.None, 8, 1)
        ' comPort.DtrEnable = True
        comPort.ReadTimeout = 500
        Do
            comPort.WriteLine("Go")
            Dim sIncomming As String = comPort.ReadLine()

            tbxIn.Text = sIncomming & vbCrLf
        Loop
    Catch ex As TimeoutException
        tbxIn.Text &= "Error: Serial Port Read Timeout" & vbCrLf
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    comPort.Close()
    Button1.Enabled = True
    Button2.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    tbxIn.Text = e.ToString
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Any error is shown? The "Go" is being sent correctly?

Comment: Please see that ReadLine will not return until a enter/newline is received. Have you tried using ReadChar ?

Comment: Go gets sent fine, there is no error - it just sits there with nothing coming through to the textbox tbxIn.

Comment: Can you read the data off of the serial port with any other program?

Comment: I have got it going using a serial port component (sorry about formatting not working for me):
 `    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        ' new thread waiting for data to receive on opened com port
        Dim sString As String = comPort.ReadExisting
        MsgBox(sString)
    End Sub`

Comment: if this worked then post it as answer

Answer (score 1):

PRetty sure this will get you what you need.  You DON't need the Serial1 component on the designer.  Remove that and use this code:

```
    Private comPort As IO.Ports.SerialPort = Nothing
Private sComPort As String = ""

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    GetSerialPortNames()
End Sub

Sub GetSerialPortNames()


    ' Show all available COM ports.    
    For Each sp As String In My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames
        lstPorts.Items.Add(sp)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub lstPorts_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstPorts.SelectedIndexChanged
    sComPort = lstPorts.SelectedItem
    Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    ' Open the serial port using the OpenSerialPort method    
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Button2.Enabled = True
    Try


        comPort = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort(sComPort, 9600, IO.Ports.Parity.None, 8, 1)
        ' comPort.DtrEnable = True      

        'must add handler
        AddHandler comPort.DataReceived, AddressOf SerialPort1_DataReceived

        comPort.ReadTimeout = 500
        Do
            comPort.WriteLine("Go")
            Dim sIncomming As String = comPort.ReadLine()
            tbxIn.Text = sIncomming & vbCrLf
        Loop
    Catch ex As TimeoutException
        tbxIn.Text &= "Error: Serial Port Read Timeout" & vbCrLf
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    comPort.Close()
    'remove handler
    RemoveHandler comPort.DataReceived, AddressOf SerialPort1_DataReceived
    Button1.Enabled = True
    Button2.Enabled = False
End Sub
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    tbxIn.Text = e.ToString
End Sub
```